# Question regarding sets of vectors and linear combinations.

Tags: linear-algebra

I stumbled on this passus in a material that I am reading to better understand linear independence. (the material can be found here: http://www.math.msu.edu/~redden/309f10/supp1.pdf)

---

The set $e_1, e_2, e_3, u = (2, 0, 1)$ is a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}3$, Why?

*Can someone please explain what the line above actually means?*

Here the vector $\vec{v} = (1, 0, 1)$ can be written as a linear combination of these $4$ vectors in at least two dierent ways:

$\vec{v} = 1e_1 + 0e_2 + 1e_3 + 0u$

$\vec{v} = (-1)e_1 + 0e_2 + 0e_3 + 1u$

*The first definition of the vector v I can understand, but I don't understand how the second definition works...*

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nowhere in the text have I found anything that says $$\{e_1,e_2,e_3,u\} = (2,0,1).$$
Can you explain where in the text the problem lies? Most people here (me included) will not go reading 10 of something just to answer one question about one part of it...

Comment: The line "The set ${e_1 ,e_2 ,e_3 ,u } =(2,0,1)$  is a spanning set of R3" makes no sense. (2, 0, 1) is a single vector in R3 but ${e_1 ,e_2 ,e_3 ,u }$ is a set of four vectors.

Comment: Now I see what it is. The answer below answers everything. Anyway, if the vectors $x,y,z$ span $\mathbb R^3$, then any set containing them also spans $\mathbb R^3$ (it is not, however, linearly independent).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it was my mistake when I posted the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that every vector in $\mathbb R^3$ can be written as a linear combination of $e_1 , e_2 , e_3$ and $u$, where $u = (2,0,1)$.  You have written the second equation incorrectly.  It should be written:

$$\vec{v} = (-1)e_1 + 0e_2 + 0e_3 + u$$

You can verify that this is correct as well, and so there is no unique representation of $v$ in terms of $\{ e_1,e_2,e_3,u \}$ (you will learn that this means that these vectors are *linearly dependent*).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Makes sense!!